# Json Value not echoing

Tags: curl, json

I'm trying to echo access token and it's setting a variable to false instead of the value of the page. Why is this?

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        code => 'SUPER SECRET',
        redirect_url=> 'http://example.com/wafds.php',
        client_id=> 'SECRET,
        client_secret=> 'SECRET',
        grant_type=> 'authorization_code'
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
echo json_encode($resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net/curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), curl_exec

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. Your curl is returning false hence you see the false.

Comment: any reason why it might fail?

Comment: from php.net again, string curl_error ( resource $ch ) - returns the error message for the last curl operation. why dont you try printing the error by doing a: print curl_error($curl);

Comment: client_id=> 'SECRET, <-- you are missing a closing '

Answer (score 0):

Try with SSL verifier as false:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0, 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        code => 'SUPER SECRET',
        redirect_url=> 'http://example.com/wafds.php',
        client_id=> 'SECRET,
        client_secret=> 'SECRET',
        grant_type=> 'authorization_code'
    )
));
```

Comment: So if I use this http://pastebin.com/Z5m23c4d I can echo out the results but I get {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}. When I add in the google required header application type, the error goes away but the results don't echo